# Merge two select queries sql

Tags: sql, oracle, multiple-select-query

Hey i'm using oracle sql to create a database.

I im now working on queries and i have come up with two seperate quires which i would like to merge in order to get a result.

The first query i have created is to find out the total money made by a performance:

```
    SELECT SUM(bookings * CategoryPrice )AS Total_Money_Made
    FROM ( SELECT CategoryPrice , count(*) AS bookings
       FROM Booking b
       JOIN performance per
         ON b.performanceid =  per.performanceid
       JOIN Production p
         ON per.productionid = p.productionid          
      WHERE per.performanceid IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
      GROUP BY CategoryPrice)
```

This gives me a result of:

### TOTAL_MONEY_MADE

```
       337.5
```

Then i have another query which works out the total concession money:

```
              SELECT SUM(ConsessionAmount * 2) AS Total_Consession_Money
      FROM( SELECT COUNT (*) AS ConsessionAmount
FROM Booking 
WHERE 
Consession = 'Yes' AND PerformanceID = '1' OR 
Consession = 'Yes' AND PerformanceID = '2' OR 
Consession = 'Yes' AND PerformanceID = '3' OR 
Consession = 'Yes' AND PerformanceID = '4' )
```

This gives me result of:

### TOTAL_CONSESSION_MONEY

```
                18
```

Now i want a way that i can subtract the result from the second query from the first query. is it possible? and how can i do it? i think it has something to do with sub-queries but im not too sure.

Any help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
WITH TOTAL_MADE
AS
(   
    SELECT SUM(bookings * CategoryPrice )AS Total_Money_Made
    FROM ( SELECT CategoryPrice , count(*) AS bookings
       FROM Booking b
       JOIN performance per
         ON b.performanceid =  per.performanceid
       JOIN Production p
         ON per.productionid = p.productionid          
      WHERE per.performanceid IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
      GROUP BY CategoryPrice)
), TOTAL_CONSESSION
AS
(
    SELECT SUM(ConsessionAmount * 2) AS Total_Consession_Money
      FROM( SELECT COUNT (*) AS ConsessionAmount
    FROM Booking 
    WHERE 
    Consession = 'Yes' AND PerformanceID = '1' OR 
    Consession = 'Yes' AND PerformanceID = '2' OR 
    Consession = 'Yes' AND PerformanceID = '3' OR 
    Consession = 'Yes' AND PerformanceID = '4' )
)
SELECT
    TOTAL_CONSESSION.Total_Consession_Money-
    TOTAL_MADE.Total_Money_Made AS Something
FROM
    TOTAL_MADE,
    TOTAL_CONSESSION;
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Worked like a charm!!

Answer (score 1):

you can use select in select sentence using parenthesis

```
select (put your second query here) - (put your first select here) from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like:

```
SELECT Total_Money_Made - Total_Consession_Money FROM

( SELECT SUM(bookings * CategoryPrice )AS Total_Money_Made, ( SELECT SUM(ConsessionAmount * 2) AS Total_Consession_Money
      FROM( SELECT COUNT (*) AS ConsessionAmount
FROM Booking 
WHERE 
Consession = 'Yes' AND PerformanceID = '1' OR 
Consession = 'Yes' AND PerformanceID = '2' OR 
Consession = 'Yes' AND PerformanceID = '3' OR 
Consession = 'Yes' AND PerformanceID = '4' )
    FROM ( SELECT CategoryPrice , count(*) AS bookings
       FROM Booking b
       JOIN performance per
         ON b.performanceid =  per.performanceid
       JOIN Production p
         ON per.productionid = p.productionid          
      WHERE per.performanceid IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
      GROUP BY CategoryPrice) )
```